# C++ Standard doesn't say anything about operator!=() and operator==() for enum classes

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, operator-overloading, language-lawyer

**Section 7.2 Enumeration declarations** doesn't say anything about the `operator!=()` and the `operator==()` for a scoped enumeration. But the code below compiles.

```
#include <iostream>

enum class Month{jan = 1, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov , dec};

int main()
{
    Month a = Month::feb;
    Month b = Month::jul;
    Month c = a;

    if( a != b ) std::cout << "a |= b" << '\n';
    if( a == c ) std::cout << "a == c" << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Why are you expecting it shouldn't? The standard doesn't say something about these operators for `int` in particular either.

Comment: @MikeSeymour §5.10 also doesn't say anything for enum classes.

Comment: @WakeupBrazil: Indeed, it defers to 5.9. I've extended my comment into an answer, since it's not entirely trivial.

Comment: @PeterHorvath hence my empiricist answer, such things gave rise to GNUC, and a lot of other things which eventually become standard (example BOOST)

Comment: Being able to compare using `==` and having an `operator==` function are two subtly different things. The latter would allow an explicit call using the `operator==` name.

Comment: @hvd that's being pedantic and historical, it's like saying "int* has a destructor - it just does nothing" it makes the idea of a variable at the end of the scope destroying itself consistent, and the fact it does nothing (and I wouldn't have it any other way) practical.

Comment: @PeterHorvath I find your description of the committee members quite arrogant.

Comment: @AlecTeal The OP observed that `operator==` shouldn't be defined, and concluded that therefore, `==` shouldn't work. I was pointing out that the observation that `operator==` shouldn't be defined is correct, but the conclusion that `==` therefore shouldn't work isn't. When trying to grok the standard, that level of pedantry is useful. (Also, sometimes the ability to refer to overloaded operators by name is useful, for example when passing the operator function by reference as a callback. The fact that that is not possible for built-in operators on custom enum types may be important.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The built-in operators are specified in 5.10:

> The == (equal to) and the != (not equal to) operators have the same semantic restrictions, conversions, and result type as the relational operators except for their lower precedence and truth-value result.

This defers the specification to that of the relational operators in 5.9; for enumerations that's specified by 5.9/5:

> If both operands (after conversions) are of arithmetic **or enumeration** type, each of the operators shall yield true if the specified relationship is true and false if it is false.

So, as one might expect, the comparison operators are applicable to enumerations, comparing the numeric values.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer with some reluctance. It seems like the Standard is not entirely correct on this point. That's probably the reason why they changed the wording in §5.10 in the drafts for C++14, as shown in Vlad's answer.

Comment: @WakeupBrazil The standard is correct, as it validates itself ;)

Comment: @WakeupBrazil: I don't know what you mean by "not entirely correct". I agree that a standalone specification (per C++14) is clearer than deferring to another specification; but as far as I can see both are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

From the C++ Standard

> 5.10 Equality operators [expr.eq] 1 The == (equal to) and the != (not equal to) operators group left-to-right. The operands shall have
>   arithmetic, **enumeration**, pointer, or pointer to member type, or
>   type std::nullptr_t. The operators == and != both yield true or false,
>   i.e., a result of type bool. In each case below, the operands shall
>   have the same type after the specified conversions have been applied.

As you see enumerations independing of whether they are scoped or unscoped can be used in equality operators

Comment: 5.10 in the C++11 Standard is not what you posted above.

Comment: @Wake up Brazil  I posted from the Draft #N3691 date 2013-05-16. It seems it is the Draft of the C++ 2014.:)

Comment: @WakeupBrazil: This appears to be from the [C++14 draft](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3797.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

The WHOLE POINT of enums is an equality (and not) test. `int`s have an order, 1<2, but `EMPTY` `WHITE` and `BLACK` (if you haev an Othello board say, it just so happens I was working on one 2 hours ago) is `WHITE`>`BLACK`, what about `WHITE%EMPTY`, no, but the WHOLE POINT is so I can say

```
switch(board.get_square(x,y)) {
    case Piece::WHITE:
        magic();
        break;
    case Piece::BLACK:
        whatever();
        break;
    default:
 }
```

For an `enum class Piece;` of course.

case is like an equality comparison I am saying:

```
if(board.get_square(x,y) == Piece::WHITE) {
```

or something.

Comment: @DarkCthulhu what dont you get?